# Putting data into database with random form data

Tags: javascript, php

Well it's hard to explain but I've made an option menu

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p><h2 id="title">Add stuff here</h2></p>
        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" id="myTable">
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Add Option">
        <script>
            var totalcells = 0
            function test(){
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(totalcells);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                totalcells++
                cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='Option Title' onclick='select()'>";
                cell2.innerHTML = "<textarea onclick='select()'>Text</textarea>";
                }
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Each time a user clicks on the "Add option" button a new table row appears. What I want is that when they click on submit all the above data will be stored in my database. I know how to store it when you don't have the add option but this is more complicated.

Comment: You'll need to make an ajax request.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do (sample code)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="option[]" value="first value" />
<input type="text" name="option[]" value="second value" />
```

Note the brackets in the `name`. This will create an array in the `POST`. Then you send the values to the server with `AJAX` and the `serialize()` function in `jQuery`.

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['option'] as $option):
    //your logic goes here
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't give a sure solution without seeing all the code, but here is what you would want to do:

You loop through each row / input that was submitted using a foreach and insert a new row to the DB for each result.